# Using tables created in one dataset in another dataset. SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssrs-2008

i have the following problem, i have executed a stored procedure, i have used the output generated there in one form. Now i want to create another dataset and use that same output in another form, but i don't want to reexecute this stored procedure once more, it takes much time. How can i use table generated in one dataset in another dataset? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a cached dataset, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee636149.aspx .